# Start and set up web service before running Android acceptance tests that use it

Tags: android, web-services, automated-tests, acceptance-testing

I have an Android app that depends on a web service for data.  I'd like to set up automated end-to-end acceptance tests that run against the app, with the web service being part of the 'black box'.  Is it even an option to start and set up the web service from my instrumentation tests before the tests are executed?  Or does this need to happen elsewhere, outside the instrumentation tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be a way to do this.

However, the [Robotium RC](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/wiki/RemoteControl) project, which is currently in beta, looks promising. "With Remote Control, you will have the test classes run in your computer with normal JUnit... "

There's also [RoboRemote](https://github.com/groupon/robo-remote).